# cURL https connection

Tags: php, curl

I have a problem connecting to https url while using php version 5.3.2 and curl version 7.19.7. its a very small piece of code but here is the updatet version of my php code

```
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    /* prepare a stream for writing verbose data to */
    $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $certificate );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6 );

    /* verbose logging */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );


    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials );


    $res=(object)array(
        'response'  =>  curl_exec( $ch ),
        'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $ch ),
        'errors'    =>  curl_error( $ch )
    );
    echo 'test2'; die;
    curl_close( $ch );

    rewind( $vbh );
    $res->debug=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
    fclose( $vbh );

    echo '<pre>',print_r($res,true),'</pre>';
```

this returns me this page [image]

how ever if i use the exec methode on the same location like this

```
$url = "https://lms.lifeline.nl/mailwebservice/inline";
    exec("curl $url", $output, $status);
    print_r($output);
```

i get a result back like this[image] and it never reaches the echo 'test2'; die; part of my code

here are the data that i use in evry var:

```
$data ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mail="http://www.enovation.nl/ems/mailwebservice">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <mail:ListRequest>
      <mail:accountId>***********</mail:accountId>
    </mail:ListRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

        $url = 'https://lms.lifeline.nl/mailwebservice/inline/';

        $certificate = "full path to crt file";

        $headers = array( 
            'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"', 
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($data), 
            'Accept: text/xml', 
            'Cache-Control: no-cache', 
            'Pragma: no-cache', 
            'SOAPAction: "Send"'
        );

        $credentials = "$username:$password";
```

i can't figure out why in section 1 i can't get a response and it kills my code and why in section 2 i do get a response.

also it seems my cURL loops trying to connect to the url.

Comment: is that the entire curl code? the url given above prompts immediately for authorization so your code would need to factor in http auth, probbly to use ssl certificates, to verify server etc and to follow redirects

Comment: well this was not my full version this was https://codeshare.io/ayD110 but because curl_exec breaks i can not use the curl_error to check whats wrong whit the request

Answer (score 1):

You might get more information if you were to try implementing some of / all of this:

```
/* details copied from externally linked file */

$credentials = "username:password";

$body='oapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mail="http://www.enovation.nl/ems/mailwebservice">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <mail:ListRequest>
      <mail:accountId>**********</mail:accountId>
    </mail:ListRequest>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';
```

The SOAP body ought, I think, to look more like this:

```
$body='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mail="http://www.enovation.nl/ems/mailwebservice">
  <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
    <mail:ListRequest>
      <mail:accountId>3456845125</mail:accountId>
    </mail:ListRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';


$headers = array( 
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"', 
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body), 
    'Accept: text/xml', 
    'Cache-Control: no-cache', 
    'Pragma: no-cache', 
    'SOAPAction: "Send"'
);



$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

/* prepare a stream for writing verbose data to */
$vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $certificate );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6 );

/* verbose logging */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );


curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body ); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $credentials );

$res=(object)array(
    'response'  =>  curl_exec( $ch ),
    'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $ch ),
    'errors'    =>  curl_error( $ch )
);
curl_close( $ch );

rewind( $vbh );
$res->debug=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
fclose( $vbh );

echo '<pre>',print_r($res,true),'</pre>';
```

Comment: this gives me more information when i can get the connection startet for sure but it runs in to the same problem that en where filing response => curl_exec($ch), the code stops working and the same error page pops up

Comment: Are you sure that you are supplying all the correct details - we have no idea what you have supplied in some of those variables, such as `$credentials`, `$headers` or `$body` which doesn't really help solve the conundrum. I appreciate username/password details are not to be shared but a redacted ( censored ) version of the variables might help - along with the full code that you actually use

Comment: oow i am sory these var are set above what i share here a link to everything inside the curl var that are unknown https://codeshare.io/GqNwnx

Comment: I have updated my not-an-answer answer with the details you provided from the link. One thing to note is the syntax errors and missing chars from the soap body... I keep getting a malformed error but probably not surprising given the data. Is there some documentation somewhere from the provider?? You really ought to update your question to include all the relevant information btw

Comment: i have updated the post to the current version i have running whit all the spec's that come whit it. ty for pointing out the soap error however this did not solve the connection problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this to disable ssl verification

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://lms.lifeline.nl/mailwebservice/inline/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: same problem i still get the connection was reset page

Comment: Do you use an proxy?

Comment: no this is not the case however when i run this cURL on my local workstation using usbwebserver and not on the server i do get a response back